# Baking Issues - unable to successfully bake my normals

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I am having problems baking my sculpt to my lowpoly model, I'm getting what looks like to be the outline of my UV's, not sure why. When I use the smart project, things look as the should (for the most part), using the smart project is not reasonable for a human figure. Originally this model was in zbrush if that helps with some clues.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the low-poly model's normals correct? Have you tried upping the "ray distance" in the baking menu? Other than that, it might help to add the resulting normal map to your post, to help give a sense of what's going wrong.

Comment: I had to run off to work, but after work i'll check the normals for the low poly, the low poly was generated using Quad Remesher, because doing retopology sucks, that turns out being the culprit i'll be very disappointed.